# Opening an url in the background with swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to open an url in the background to update my database with information,
but it should not open safari because customer shouldn't be able to see the php link.

would be glad for any help, 
i just need help to open the URL in the background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is an HTTP request. This is what browsers do to get content from a webpage. There are many ways to do an HTTP request to a url in iOS. One such way is with the URLSession class.

```
let url = URL(string: "http://www.google.com/") //Or your URL
var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.httpBody = "Data to send to your backend".data(using: .utf8)!

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    if error != nil {
        //There was an error
    } else {
        //The HTTP request was successful
        print(String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)!)
    }

}
task.resume()
```

This will send the data in the `httpBody` property to your backend in a HTTP request.